# Why is Schröder numbers equivalent to the number of perfect matchings for triangular grid of n squares and how the graph look like?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, lattices, perfect-matchings

In the OEIS entry for the [Schröder numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der_number) is [A006318](https://oeis.org/A006318). There is a comment which related the sequence to perfect matchings:

> The number of perfect matchings in a triangular grid of n squares (n = 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, ...). - Roberto E. Martinez II, Nov 05 2001

I am not sure how the triangular grid of n squares look like. Taking my understanding as an example, I draw the graphs as following:
[image: triangle]

Let's ignore the case for `n=1`, then the perfect matchings for triangular lattice with `n=2`,`3`,`4` are `2`,`6`,`0`(which is not matched in [A006318](https://oeis.org/A006318): 2, 6, 22, ...).

So maybe I misunderstand the comment about the definition of **a triangular grid of n squares** .

- Can someone know how the graphs look like?
- Why is Schröder numbers equivalent to the number of perfect matchings in a triangular grid?

I am very happy to hear from anyone and thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Perhaps https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307851/why-is-the-number-of-perfect-matchings-in-a-triangular-grid-equivalent-to-the-nu answers your question?

Comment: @SamHopkins, thanks! I somehow want to know how the triangular grid of n squares look like.

Comment: Here's another link, directly to a pdf (https://www.emis.de/journals/JACO/Volume5_2/m24482170h4470l6.fulltext.pdf). See figure 13.

Comment: I think i found out how the graph look like in your linked pdf (probably Figure 13), thank you!@SamHopkins

Comment: yes, it helps a lot but somehow I still don't fully understand the connection just from intuition.  Probably I need to understand these literature references.

Comment: Not that another reference is needed, but see also Problem A50(v) on page 129 of my book *Catalan Numbers*.

Comment: that's a helpful book and many examples in the book, thank you very much!@RichardStanley